# Multidimensional array BigQuery

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

In bigQuery is possible delcare an Array of Array like this

DECLARE ar2 ARRAY  DEFAULT [['A','B','C'],['G','H','I'],['N','O','P']];

This syntax return error and I didn't find the right.

Comment: looks like you're dealing with arrays of arrays scenario, take a look at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#building_arrays_of_arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need to work with array of arrays, if so the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#building_arrays_of_arrays) says:

> BigQuery does not support building arrays of arrays directly. Instead,
> you must create an array of structs, with each struct containing a
> field of type ARRAY

The page also gives a solution for that by using a array of structs. May something like:

```
DECLARE ar2 DEFAULT (
WITH words AS
  (SELECT ['A','B','C'] as word
   UNION ALL SELECT ['G','H','I'] as word
   UNION ALL SELECT  ['N','O','P'] as word)
SELECT ARRAY(
  SELECT STRUCT(word)
  FROM words)
  AS all_words);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have array of arrays on BigQuery. It does not support it. As per documentation about [Declaring an ARRAY type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#declaring_an_array_type) shows:

> ARRAY<ARRAY>
> (not supported) This is an invalid type declaration which is included here just in case you came looking for how to create a multi-level ARRAY. ARRAYs cannot contain ARRAYs directly. Instead see the next example.

But there are workarounds for it, like using [array](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array_type) with [structs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#struct_type). Please see below code:

```
DECLARE TEST ARRAY<STRUCT<x ARRAY<STRING>,y ARRAY<STRING>,z ARRAY<STRING>>> 
DEFAULT[(['A','B','C'],['E','F'],['W','X','Y','Z'])];

SELECT TEST;
```

Comment: Hello @user9846973, have you managed to make it work?